# Find if Update happened or not in PDO Php

Tags: php

I am using following code to update my query. Suppose my ability value was 0 and this update didn't happen. How can I find out?

```
$statement = $conn->prepare ('UPDATE players SET 
                   ability = ability - 1 WHERE id = :playerId AND ability > 0');

$statement->bindParam (':playerId', $player['id'],PDO::PARAM_INT);

$statement->execute();
```

Comment: AFAIK the only reliable way is to do a select before and after the update and see if it's been changed.

Comment: doesn't PDO execute returns true on successful execution of query.. it wont give you the information that the update happened with your data but it does provide the information that the update query was executed successfully..http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE.....");
$stmt->execute(array($var, $var));
```

Now, if you want to check for success update..

```
if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
    //means updated
}else{
   //means not updated
}
```

Comment: And what if the update changes more than one field? *giggity*

Comment: Will still get the same...(Ithink) or you can check using `var_dump($stmt->rowCount())` for actually numbers

Comment: rowCount() will return number of affected rows and this example code will return True only if number of rows is exactly 1.

Comment: Well, professor, why are you asking me, if you already know :)

Comment: @PHPfan because it's not the OP ;) but you just have to change the check to `rowCount() > 0`

Comment: Now you've made it actually worse as it will return true ONLY when it finds more than 1 result. Proper syntax, as @Jon pointed out is rowCount() > 0.

Answer (score 0):

[According to the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.exec.php) PDO->exec will return number of affected rows, so after executing if it returns 0 then you know that nothing got updated.

Comment: And if you continued reading the documentation, you'd see that that function call doesn't work for prepared statements - and the query needs to be properly escaped before using it.

Comment: Which is very easy to do for anyone working with PDO and skips another call to database to get number of rows (which here is completely unnecessary).